# weird error popped up with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am using active_admin and devise in a project. There is an admin page to invite users that won't even load at all. I have tried removing quite a bit of code to get some clues as to what is going on. All I get is the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Admin/invitations#index

Showing /Users/ianseabock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activeadmin-0.6.2/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `storage_total_stat_id_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::User:0x007fb9ebde5ce0>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

The undefined method "storage_total_stat_id_eq" is no where to be found in the codebase. Any suggestions on what's going on?

Comment: If github says the build is failing, could that be the cause  of my problems? https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin

Comment: I had that error after creating a habtm relationship. Removing the filter as per seanlinsley's answer worked for me.

Comment: I'm using rbenv and when I changed branches it lost my local setting for the project directory. ruby -v and rbenv local versionString put my gems and ruby back in the right places and got rid of this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like this is caused by an association that Active Admin is trying to build a filter for, but I'm guessing the association is non-standard. You can see which filters are being built by default with this bit of code:

```
ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources[:User].filters
```

A quick fix would be to remove that filter:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # ...

  remove_filter :storage_total_stat

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have included the `storage_total_stat_id` has been included in the permitted parameters:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Invitation do
    permit_params :storage_total_stat_id, :other, :attributes, :for, :this, :model
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - and for me it was that my Active Admin form included a "collection" filter that was incorrectly specified.

I had used User.all.where(...) instead of User.where(...).

Once I removed the ".all", it fixed the problem.