# How to fix Ransack undefined method "_eq", when using ActiveAdmin with ":through" relationships in your model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I have a Rails 4.0.1 application, using gems activeadmin 1.0.0.pre and ransack 1.1.0.

Using ActiveAdmin, I have many errors like this one :

```
NoMethodError in Admin::MyModel#action
Showing [...]/views/active_admin/resource/action.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `applied_boundaries_id_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x0..>
Extracted source (around line #1): insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

There is a pattern "_eq" for each undefined method :

```
aws_instance_type_clients_id_eq
user_roles_id_eq
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer right here : [undefined method `users_user_id_eq' for Ransack::Search](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2565)

There is also a post here : [weird error popped up with active admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868466/weird-error-popped-up-with-active-admin) that looks to be the same problem description.

It seems that Ransack (used by ActiveAdmin) do not like `has many .. :through` relationships.

Example :

If you have a `user.rb` that `has many :roles, :through => :user_roles`

This will give you the error : `undefined method user_roles_id_eq`

To fix (not really fix.. but avoid to get an error) the bug, edit your "ActiveAdmin.register User" file, and add : `remove_filter :user_roles`

Comment: At the time (few years) I was unable to truly fix it.